# What would be the nature of the plot of electrical conductivity of a metal with absolute temperature?

Tags: electricity, superconductivity, thermoelectricity

What should precisely be the equation of the curve of electrical conductivity of a metal and absolute temperature?
Will the conductivity approach infinity at zero kelvin?

Comment: Have you even tried searching the internet? Electrical conductivity decreases as the temperature increases for metals.

Comment: Yes, but I'm a bit confused about the nature of the curve.

Comment: Write about the confusion in your question.

Comment: I did. I asked for the plot.

Comment: Not all metals are superconductors. Not all metals exhibit a monotonic increase in conductivity as the temperature decreases. Solid state physics is not simple.

Comment: There has been no research done or effort taken to answer these questions.  When you say you are confused about the nature of the curve where is the curve that you are referring to?

Comment: Ill-formulated as it may be, this is actually a very important question. The basics of "THE TEMPERATURE-DEPENDENT ELECTRICAL RESISTIVITY
OF METALS", generally linear well above the Debye temperature, $\propto T^5$ well below, are discussed in Ch. 26 of Ashcroft-Mermin. There's much more to the topic (Umklapp processes, saturation or lack thereof, Planckian dissipation...).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

A quick Google search brought up this [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electrical_resistivity_and_conductivity#Temperature_dependence) page

> As the temperature of the metal is sufficiently reduced (so as to 'freeze' all the phonons), the resistivity usually reaches a constant value, known as the residual resistivity. This value depends not only on the type of metal, but on its purity and thermal history. The value of the residual resistivity of a metal is decided by its impurity concentration. Some materials lose all electrical resistivity at sufficiently low temperatures, due to an effect known as superconductivity.